#  Ruby and Rails code completion issues in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

Compared to the code completion I am familiar with from C# development, I find the code completion offered by RubyMine surprisingly incomplete.

1. When I write a class with some methods and I want to call them from another class,
   why am I getting a code-completion list that is like "a mile" long, but with no relevant method-suggestions in it?
   ( Or is this a bug/feature in my RubyMine?! )
2. Some classes like `ActionMailer` *magically* generate methods like the "deliver_*" methods ( see this [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-send-email.htm) )... As I don't see them in code completion how am I supposed to know they even exist?
   ( Unfortunately I also get an error at the moment, that `deliver_contact` method does not exist... As I completely copied from the example am asking myself now wheter this feature still exists 8[ )

Are they any ways to fix these issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that Ruby wasn't "designed" to be used with code completion, it's that behavior can be added in a variety of ways, including during program execution. This makes code completion *hard*. RubyMine does a good job, but only for obvious or known functionality, when an object's type is known.

http://apidock.com provides reference material for Ruby, Rails, and RSpec. Playing around in irb/[pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) can help a lot. You can always get methods on a class/instance by eval-ing `foo.methods` in a REPL (although I almost always `foo.methods.sort`).

That list can be filtered if you "sort of" know what you're looking for with find/grep, e.g.

```
> "foo".class.instance_methods(false).sort.grep /each/
=> [:each_byte, :each_char, :each_codepoint, :each_line]
```

In the Rails environment, running `rails console` (I prefer using pry for the console, YMMV) gives you access to your environment, including exposing a lot of the dynamic methods. Note that some methods do not exist until they are called for the first time (notably those of the `find_by_foo_and_bar` variety) so some functionality may *still* be hidden.

Comment: The truth is though that most coders on the Ruby/Rails core teams use just text editors.

Comment: @JakubHampl So? Doesn't mean it's the most efficient thing to do (it isn't), or that everyone does, or that you can't use both (I use both).

Comment: Dave I always enjoy your postings and love this one.  Yes I use multiple OS's (MAC/Win/U) and many editors and IDE's.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Thanks; that's very kind. Yeah, the whole IDE v. text editor thing confuses me--right tool for the job, and they all have their places, strengths, and weaknesses!

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you get these problems is that Ruby(onRails) was never designed to be used with code completion. Most Rubyist code in a text editor and are very happy that they don't need code completion.

In the current version of Rails the deliver_* methods are deprecated in favour of `MyClass.contact.deliver` style.

Comment: ok, thanks for the hint but it doesn't really answer my question.. how do you "know" of the methods of a class.. or do you read it up on the internet? ^^

Comment: You'll find yourself reading source a lot, or docs when available. Style varies between programmers of course, but many Ruby libraries rely heavily on meta-programming and dynamically written methods.  Such techniques simply don't lend themselves well to auto-completion.

Comment: @David Dave answered that pretty well. After you have some experience with Rails you often just guess :) apidock is a great site, I use it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

All the method that follow the following structure: deliver_* are using the
meta programming philosophy.

Here's a very simple example: [Ruby: define_method vs. def](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185947/ruby-define-method-vs-def)

You will find that a lot of stuff in rails has to do with method missing and the meta programming philosophy.