# Ruby define_method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have the following test which I must pass:

```
def test_can_find_by_arbitrary_fields
  assert @library.respond_to? :find_by_artist
  assert !@library.respond_to?(:find_by_bitrate)
  @library.add_song({ :artist => 'Green Day',
                     :name => 'American Idiot',
                     :bitrate => 192 })
  assert @library.respond_to?(:find_by_bitrate)
end
```

and I am not sure how I can do it.

I tried doing:

```
def respond_to?(method)
     if self.public_methods.include? method
         true
     elsif (method == :find_by_bitrate)
         define_method :find_by_bitrate, ->(default = nrb)  { @songs.select |a| a[:bitrate] == nrb }       
         false
     else
         false
end
```

but it says "define_method is undefined". Are there any ways I can define the `find_by_bitrate` method?

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to be redefining `respond_to?`? I suspect that's very much not what you want to do. At the very least you almost definitely do not want to be defining a method in `respond_to?`.

Comment: Not really. But I can't think of any other way of inserting the find_by_bitrate after the first time it's not found.

Comment: But `respond_to?` isn't called when trying to call a method on an object, so unless your actual app code calls `respond_to?` it won't define `find_by_bitrate`. Are you using Ruby 1.9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may define methods the first time they're called in `method_missing`.

Whether or not you *should* is open to some debate, but it's a better option than `respond_to?`.

```
class Foo
  def method_missing(sym)
    puts "Method missing; defining."
    self.class.send(:define_method, sym) do
      puts "Called #{sym}."
    end
  end
end
```

Sanity check:

```
f = Foo.new
=> #<Foo:0x007fa6aa09d3c0>
f.wat
=> Method wat missing; defining.
f.wat
=> Called wat.
f2 = Foo.new
=> Called wat.
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be redefining `respond_to?` method. The point of the test is (probably) that the `@library` object should have a `find_by_artist` method defined and no `find_by_bitrate` until you add a song with a bitrate. I.e. the `add_song` method should define method `find_by_bitrate` when it sees a song with a bitrate (?).

Also, `define_method` is a private method of `Class`. Above, you're trying to call it from an instance method. See "[Ruby: define_method vs. def](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185947/ruby-define-method-vs-def)", there's more on this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of info missing to properly answer this.  The test implies that `find_by_artist` is always defined even when `@library` is empty, but that there are dynamic methods available on other attributes (eg: bitrate) that are valid only when library contains a record with such a method.

One should not redefine `respond_to?` in any case. There is an explicit hook method for answering respond_to? for dynamic methods: [`Object#respond_to_missing?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-respond_to_missing-3F).

So a simple way to make your test pass is to be sure the @library object has a concrete method `#find_by_artist` and a respond to hook that checks whether any of it's elements a have the requested attribute.  If I assume @library is a collection object `Library` which keeps an enumeration of songs in `@songs`

```
class Library
  def find_by_artist artist
    @songs.select { |song| song['artist'] == artist }
  end

  def method_missing meth, arg
    m = /^find_by_(.+)$/.match meth.to_s
    return super unless attr = m && m[1]

    @songs.select { |song| song[attr] ==  arg }
  end

  def respond_to_missing? meth, include_private
    m = /^find_by_(.+)$/.match meth.to_s
    return super unless attr = m && m[1]

    @songs.any? { |song| song.has_key? attr }
  end
end
```

This has a performance problem in that respond_to? now incurs a search of all the songs.  One could optimize by keeping a set of the union of all attributes contained in @songs and updating it in methods which add/update/delete elements in the collection.